# How to manage color lines in tables?

Tags: tables, color, colortbl

I've created a table using the website: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/, but I've a problem with some lines. How can I delete white lines in the first column of the following table (the ones indicated by the red arrows)?

[image]

This is the code that I've obtained from website:

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{adjustbox}{width=\columnwidth,center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{F54A19}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} } &
 \textbf{Weight} &
 34 g (sun sensor) + 1 g (mounting hardware) \\ \cline{2-3} 
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{F54A19}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} } &
 \textbf{Size} &
 34 mm x 32 mm x 21 mm \\ \cline{2-3} 
\rowcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{F54A19}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} } &
 \textbf{Power} &
 37.5 mW average, 130 mW peak \\ \cline{2-3} 
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\multirow{-4}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F54A19}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{PHYSICAL CHARACTERISTICS}}} &
 \textbf{Outer Surfaces} &
 Low emissivity gold, scratch-proof sapphire \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{F54A19}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} } &
 \textbf{Accuracy} &
 ±0.1° over ±70° Field-of-View \\ \cline{2-3} 
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{F54A19}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} } &
 \textbf{Bandwidth} &
 5 vector solutions / second \\ \cline{2-3} 
\rowcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3} 
\multirow{-3}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F54A19}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{PERFORMANCES}}} &
 \textbf{Earth Albedo Error} &
 Rejected by internal digital processor \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{F54A19}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{COMMAND/TELEMETRY}} &
 \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}RS-485} \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{F54A19}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} } &
 \textbf{Supply Voltage} &
 5.0 V to 50.0 V \\ \cline{2-3} 
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{F54A19}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} } &
 \textbf{Supply Current} &
 7.5 mA average, 27 mA peak \\ \cline{2-3} 
\rowcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{F54A19}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} } &
 \cellcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3} &
 \cellcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3} \\
\rowcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{F54A19}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} } &
 \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3}\textbf{Idle Current Consumption}} &
 \multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}3 mA, bootloader mode\\ 8 mA, application mode\end{tabular}} \\ \cline{2-3} 
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\multirow{-5}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F54A19}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{POWER IN}}} &
 \textbf{Active Current Consumption} &
 \textless{}30 mA \\ \hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{F54A19}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} } &
 \textbf{Operating Temperature Range} &
 -25 °C to +75 °C \\ \cline{2-3} 
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{F54A19}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} } &
 \textbf{Survival Temperature Range} &
 -40 °C to +85 °C \\ \cline{2-3} 
\rowcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{F54A19}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} } &
 \textbf{Shock} &
 5000 g \\ \cline{2-3} 
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\cellcolor[HTML]{F54A19}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} } &
 \textbf{Random Vibration} &
 16 g rms \\ \cline{2-3} 
\rowcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3} 
\multirow{-5}{*}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F54A19}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{ENVIRONMENT}}} &
 \textbf{Radiation Tolerant} &
 20 krad total dose at components \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{SS-411 Two-Axis Digital Sun Sensors technical data [1], [2]. }
\label{tabella}
\end{table}
```

Comment: try the nicematrix package, it uses tikz to color and this has less problems with lines.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a beginner in latex world! Can you correct the first cell of my table using the package that you've mentioned ?

Comment: Unrelated to the issue itself, but please do not use `adjustbox` on a table as this will only result in inconsistent (and sometimes illegibly small) font sizes throughout the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{width=\columnwidth,center}
\begin{NiceTabular}{c>{\bfseries}cc}%
  [ 
    cell-space-top-limit=3pt ,
    cell-space-bottom-limit=3pt ,
    hvlines ,
    code-before = \rowcolors[HTML]{1}{FDDCD3}{} \columncolor[HTML]{F54A19}{1} 
  ]
 \Block{4-1}{\color{white}\makecell{PHYSICAL\\ CHARACTERISTICS}} 
 &  Weight &  34 g (sun sensor) + 1 g (mounting hardware) \\  
 &  Size &  34 mm x 32 mm x 21 mm \\  
 &  Power &  37.5 mW average, 130 mW peak \\  
 &  Outer Surfaces &  Low emissivity gold, scratch-proof sapphire \\ 
 \Block{3-1}{\color{white}PERFORMANCES} 
 & Accuracy & ±0.1° over ±70° Field-of-View \\  
 & Bandwidth & 5 vector solutions / second \\  
 & Earth Albedo Error &  Rejected by internal digital processor \\ 
 \color{white}COMMAND/TELEMETRY 
 & \Block{1-2}{RS-485} \\ 
 \Block{4-1}{\color{white}POWER IN}
 & Supply Voltage & 5.0 V to 50.0 V \\  
 & Supply Current & 7.5 mA average, 27 mA peak \\  
 & Idle Current Consumption  &
 \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}3 mA, bootloader mode\\ 8 mA, application mode\end{tabular} \\  
 &  Active Current Consumption & \textless{}30 mA \\ 
 \Block{5-1}{\color{white}ENVIRONMENT}
 & Operating Temperature Range & $-25$ °C to $+75$ °C \\  
 & Survival Temperature Range & $-40$ °C to $+85$ °C \\  
 & Shock & 5000 g \\  
 & Random Vibration & 16 g rms \\  
 &  Radiation Tolerant & 20 krad total dose at components \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{adjustbox}
 
\end{document}
```

- In `{NiceTabular}`, you use the command `\Block` to merge cells both vertically and horizontally.
- The key `hvlines` draws all the rules, excepted in the blocks.
- The command `\rowcolors` (in the key `code-before`) will color the rows alternately and the coommand `\columncolor` (used after) will color the first column.

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: @FPantigny  I am unable to use package nicematrix and nicetabular on my macbook air -- on my windows pc the packages work fine -- suggestions are welcome

Comment: @js jibra: Difficult to answer without the log file: send me an email with the log file.

Comment: @F.Pantigny I've the following warning: Environment NiceTabular undefined.
So the code does not work. Can you help me ?

Comment: @F.Pantigny I use overleaf (it'online). Is this the reason of the problem ?

Comment: @Giuseppe: By default, Overleaf uses an old version of `nicematrix`. You have to retrieve the newest version of `nicematrix.sty` ([here](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty)) and put that file next to your file in your Overleaf project (buttom 'import' next to 'new file').

Comment: Sorry @F.Pantigny, can you clarify the procedure I have to follow?

Comment: You go [here](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nicematrix/nicematrix.sty). At the *top* of the page, you have the latest version of `nicematrix`. It's the revision *56256*. You do a right click on `download` and you save the file under the name `nicematrix.sty`.

Comment: Then, you import that file nicematrix.sty in your Overleaf project with the button import. It should work. (I have modified the previous comment: the newest version is on the *top* of the page, of course).

Comment: @F.Pantigny Wonderful, it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: @F.Pantigny Just last thing: In the first block (physical charateristics) I'd like to put the word "charateristics" on the next row and I'm trying to use the command \\, so "physical \\ charateristics" but it does not work. Can you help me ?

Comment: @Giuseppe: I have modified my answer to answer your question.

Comment: @F.Pantigny Thanks!

Comment: @Giuseppe Just a note `F. Pantigny` is the author of `nicematrix.sty`....

Comment: @MadyYuvi I had noticed it