# How to Insert tables side by side

Tags: tables, excel, sidebyside

I've created two tables side by side making copy/past from excel to website tablesgenerator.com. I've deleted the central column to divide two tables but I'm not satisfied of the result because it seems that the boundaries are not well defined.

Can you help me to define separately the boundaries of two tables ?

Code:

```
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
% If you use beamer only pass "xcolor=table" option, i.e. 

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{gensymb}    
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{color}     %testo colorato
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{array, boldline, makecell, booktabs}




\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{ccc|c|c|}
\cline{1-2} \cline{4-5}
\rowcolor[HTML]{F54A19} 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F54A19}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{RDA MAIN INPUT REQUIREMENT}}} &
 \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} &
 \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{F54A19}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{ANTENNA REQUIREMENT}}} \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
\rowcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3}\textbf{Mass}} &
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3}\textless{}10 Kg} &
 \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} &
 \textbf{Carrier Frequency} &
 F0 = 35.76 GHz \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}\textbf{Power consumption}} &
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}\textless 55 W (antennas included)} &
  &
 \textbf{Antenna Beams} &
 \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}4 (available in time \\ division multiple access)\end{tabular} \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
\rowcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Altitude Operational \\ envelope\end{tabular}}} &
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Hmax = 6500 m\\ Hmin = 10 m\end{tabular}} &
 \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} &
 \textbf{TX Peak Power} &
 1 W \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Velocity Operational \\ envelope\end{tabular}}} &
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}V(vertical) \textless 115m/s} &
  &
 \textbf{TX BW} &
 200 MHz \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
\rowcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Velocity measurement \\ error\end{tabular}}} &
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3}VBi: 0.5\% V + 0,2m/s} &
 \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} &
 \textbf{Pulse width} &
 40 ÷ 2560 ns \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Altitude measurement \\ error\end{tabular}}} &
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}RBi: 0.5\% H + 0.4 m} &
  &
 \textbf{PRI} &
 10 ÷ 240 usec \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
\rowcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3}\textbf{Acceleration}} &
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}ax up to 9.3 m/s2;\\ ay, az up to 2.65 m/s2\end{tabular}} &
 \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} &
 \textbf{RX signal BW} &
 50 MHz \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}\textbf{Jerk}} &
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}jx up to 93 m/s\textasciicircum{}3\\ jy, jz up to 26.5 m/s\textasciicircum{}3\end{tabular}} &
  &
 \textbf{Refresh rate} &
 20 Hz \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
\rowcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3} 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3}\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Measure refresh \\ rate\end{tabular}}} &
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3}20 Hz} &
 \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} &
 \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Antenna sidelobe \\ level\end{tabular}} &
 \textless -35 dB \\ \cline{1-2} \cline{4-5} 
\rowcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF} 
\textbf{} &
  &
  &
 \textbf{Antenna directivity} &
 \textgreater 34 dB \\ \cline{4-5} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Below there is an example of what I've obtained exporting the pdf document. I'd like to have black lines where I've drawn blue lines
[image]

Comment: Please make your example code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the required packages. For the horizontal lines, you can use `\hline`. Since horizontal and vertical lines in tables ofter cause problems when used in combination with background colors, you might also want to take a look at the `nicematrix` package (See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/561982/134144)

Comment: Instead of using one `tabular` enviornment for both tables, I suggest using two separe `tabular` environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest a major rethink: no black rules -- or blue rules. Your readers will appreciate it.

The following solution employs a `tabularx` environment, which allows line wrapping in cells. It also cuts down as much as possible on the plethora of `\color`, `\cellcolor`, and `\rowcolor` commands, many of which are either redundant or in conflict with each other. Do use the `\SI` macro of the `siunitx` package to typeset scientific units and their associated quantities.

A final suggestion: DON'T USE ALL-CAPS HEADERS unless you want to come across as really liking to SHOUT AT YOUR READERS.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\bfseries}C}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand\cA{\color{white}}
\newcommand\rcB{\rowcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3}} % pink

\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,amsmath}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more open "look"
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ BC >{\cellcolor{white}}c BC }

\rowcolor[HTML]{F54A19} % red
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cA \textbf{RDA main input requirement}} 
&&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cA \textbf{Antenna requirement}} \\ 
  
\rcB % pink
Mass & $<\SI{10}{\kilogram}$ 
&&
Carrier Frequency & $F_0 = \SI{35.76}{\giga\hertz}$ \\  

Power consumption & $<\SI{55}{\watt}$ (antennas included) 
&&
Antenna Beams & 4 (available in time division multiple access) \\ 
 
\rcB 
Altitude Operational envelope &
\mbox{Hmax = \SI{6500}{\meter}} \mbox{Hmin = \SI{10}{\meter}} 
&&
TX Peak Power & \SI{1}{\watt} \\ 
 
Velocity Operational envelope &
$V(\text{vertical}) < \SI{115}{\meter\per\second}$ 
&&
TX BW & \SI{200}{\mega\hertz} \\ 
 
\rcB 
Velocity measurement error & VBi: 0.5\%~V + \SI{0.2}{\meter\per\second} 
&&
Pulse width & 40 ÷ \SI{2560}{\nano\second} \\ 

Altitude measurement error & RBi: 0.5\% H + \SI{0.4}{\meter} 
&&
PRI & 10 ÷ \SI{240}{\micro\second} \\  

\rcB 
Acceleration & 
\mbox{$a_x$ up to \SI{9.3}{\meter\per\second\squared}}
\mbox{$a_y$, $a_z$ up to \SI{2.65}{\meter\per\second\squared}}
&&
RX signal BW & \SI{50}{\mega\hertz} \\ 
   
Jerk &
\mbox{$j_x$ up to \SI{93}{\meter\per\second\cubed}} 
\mbox{$j_y$, $j_z$ up to \SI{26.5}{\meter\per\second\cubed}} 
&&
Refresh rate & \SI{20}{\hertz} \\ 
  
\rcB 
Measure refresh rate & \SI{20}{\hertz}
&&
Antenna sidelobe level & $<\SI{-35}{\deci\bel}$ \\ 
  
& &&
Antenna directivity & $>\SI{34}{\deci\bel}$ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: And here is how I would typeset the table in a `beamer` document. The main changes are (a) no bold-facing in columns 1 and 3, (b) make column 2 slightly wider than the other 3, and (c) use of `\scriptsize`.

I can't help but remark that this table contains way too much information to throw at an audience.

[image]

```
\documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\hsize=#1\hsize}X}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

%\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % 'xcolor' is loaded automatically by beamer
\newcommand\cA{\color{white}}
\newcommand\rcB{\rowcolor[HTML]{FDDCD3}} % pink

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\scriptsize

\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} 
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % for a more open "look"
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{C{0.97}C{1.09} >{\cellcolor{white}}c C{0.97}C{0.97}}

\rowcolor[HTML]{F54A19} % red
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cA \textbf{RDA main input requirement}} 
&&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\cA \textbf{Antenna requirement}} \\ 
  
\rcB % pink
Mass & $<\SI{10}{\kilogram}$ 
&&
Carrier frequency & $F_0 = \SI{35.76}{\giga\hertz}$ \\  

Power consumption & $<\SI{55}{\watt}$ (antennas included) 
&&
Antenna beams & 4 (available in TDMA) \\ 
 
\rcB 
Altitude operational envelope &
\mbox{Hmax = \SI{6500}{\meter}} \mbox{Hmin = \SI{10}{\meter}} 
&&
TX Peak power & \SI{1}{\watt} \\ 
 
Velocity operational envelope &
$V(\text{vertical}) <\SI{115}{\meter\per\second}$ 
&&
TX BW & \SI{200}{\mega\hertz} \\ 
 
\rcB 
Velocity measurement error &
VBi: 0.5\%~V + \SI{0.2}{\meter\per\second} 
&&
Pulse width & 40 ÷ \SI{2560}{\nano\second} \\ 

Altitude measurement error & RBi: 0.5\% H + \SI{0.4}{\meter} 
&&
PRI & 10 ÷ \SI{240}{\micro\second} \\  

\rcB 
Acceleration & 
\mbox{$a_x$ up to \SI{9.3}{\meter\per\second\squared}}
\mbox{$a_y,a_z$ up to \SI{2.65}{\meter\per\second\squared}}
&&
RX signal BW & \SI{50}{\mega\hertz} \\ 
   
Jerk &
\mbox{$j_x$ up to \SI{93}{\meter\per\second\cubed}} 
\mbox{$j_y,j_z$ up to \SI{26.5}{\meter\per\second\cubed}} 
&&
Refresh rate & \SI{20}{\hertz} \\ 
  
\rcB 
Measure refresh rate & \SI{20}{\hertz}
&&
Antenna sidelobe level & $<\SI{-35}{\deci\bel}$ \\ 
  

& &&
Antenna directivity & $>\SI{34}{\deci\bel}$ \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code and your prompts!

Comment: @Giuseppe - You're most welcome. BTW, I just posted an addendum to show how to typeset the same title as part of a beamer document.